# ¿Como manipular los datos individualmente de un array que ha sido cargado desde una consulta sql?

Tags: php, sql

Que tal soy junior en programación con php, tengo mi base de datos en MySql (XAMPP).

tengo una base de datos de la cual extraigo una lista con representantes y total de ventas de un empresa en particular, de esta manera, extraigo los datos.

```
    $ms = [];
    $db = Db::getConnect();

    //extrayendo los datos de los representantes de la empresa HELsin
    $sql = $db -> prepare('SELECT representantedoc.NameRepresentante, 
    SUM(prescripcionespediatrica.JulioRx) as julio, SUM(prescripcionespediatrica.AgostoRx) as agosto, SUM(prescripcionespediatrica.SeptiembreRx) as septiembre, SUM(prescripcionespediatrica.OctubreRx) as octubre 
    FROM representantedoc INNER JOIN prescripcionespediatrica ON representantedoc.Ruc = prescripcionespediatrica.Ruc AND (prescripcionespediatrica.Laboratory = "GINSBERG" 
    OR prescripcionespediatrica.Laboratory = "LIMERICKPHARMA" OR prescripcionespediatrica.Laboratory = "SIONPHARM" OR prescripcionespediatrica.Laboratory ="SWISS & NORTH GROU") 
    GROUP BY representantedoc.NameRepresentante');
    $sql->execute();      
    
    foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $mr){
        $ms[]=new MarketShare($mr['NameRepresentante'],  $mr['julio'], $mr['agosto'], $mr['septiembre'], $mr['octubre'] ); 
    }
```

En otro array almaceno los datos de la competencia, de esta manera

```
    $cms = [];
    $tyu = $db -> prepare('SELECT representantedoc.NameRepresentante, Sum(prescripciones.JulioRx) AS Julio, SUM(prescripciones.AgostoRx) as agosto, SUM(prescripciones.SeptiembreRx) as septiembre, SUM(prescripciones.OctubreRx) as octubre FROM representantedoc INNER JOIN prescripciones ON (representantedoc.Ruc = prescripciones.Ruc) NOT IN (prescripciones.Laboratory = "GINSBERG" OR prescripciones.Laboratory = "LIMERICKPHARMA" OR prescripciones.Laboratory = "SIONPHARM" OR prescripciones.Laboratory ="WISS & NORTH GROU") GROUP BY representantedoc.NameRepresentante');
    $tyu->execute();
    foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $mr){
        $cms[]=new MarketShare($mr['NameRepresentante'], $mr['julio'], $mr['agosto'], $mr['septiembre'], $mr['octubre'] );
    }
```

Como puedo manipular los datos individualmente de cada array para poder sumar los valores de los campos, entre los dos array, necesito hacer esto para poder calcular un porcentaje por cada representante.

Me pueden ayudar con esto por favor

MarketShare es una clase con estos atributos

```
    class MarketShare{
 //atributos
 public $representante;
 //public $lineaspe;
 public $laboratorio;
 public $julio;
 public $agosto;
 public $septiembre;
 public $octubre;

 function __construct($representante, $laboratorio, $julio, $agosto, $septiembre, $octubre){
     $this->representante=$representante;
     //$this->lineaspe=$lineaspe;
     $this->laboratorio=$laboratorio;
     $this->julio=$julio;   
     $this->agosto=$agosto;
     $this->septiembre=$septiembre;
     $this->octubre=$octubre;
 }
```

}

Comment: Lo que estas poniendo en los array son objetos MarketShare que no sabemos lo que son ni lo que devuelven, por lo tanto poco te podemos ayudar en eso.

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar si, son objetos de la clase MarketShare, que tiene atributos: class MarketShare{
     //atributos
     public $representante;
     public $laboratorio;
     public $julio;
     public $agosto;
     public $septiembre;
     public $oxtubre;}

Comment: Creo un objeto con esos atributos y lo almaceno en un array, eso hice.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿estas seguro que te estaba funcionando esa parte del código hasta ahora?  Estoy mirando de reproducirlo y cuando creas la clase para almacenarla te falta el parámetro del laboratorio y da error. Si lo quito mi respuesta funciona bien, al menos para una suma básica de los meses, luego ya es cosa tuya hacer más calculos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(he eliminado mis dos respuestas anteriores, funcionaban pero no me convencian)

Agrego finalmente esta útima respuesta, que creo que es la mejor de todas tal como lo tienes ya montado.

Se trata de recorrer los arrays con los objetos que has ido creando y mediante un condicional descubrir si son del mismo representante, y en tal caso realizar la operación de suma.

Quedaria así (no hace falta modificar tu código, tan solo agregar esto):

```php
$meses = ['julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre'];

foreach ($ms as $objMS) {
    foreach ($cms as $objCMS) {
        if($objMS->representante == $objCMS->representante) {
            foreach($meses as $mes) {
                $suma[$objMS->representante][$mes] = $objMS->$mes + $objCMS->$mes;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r($suma);
```

Lo cual nos daria algo asi:

```
Array
(
    [Antonio] => Array
        (
            [julio] => 6000
            [agosto] => 5000
            [septiembre] => 3000
            [octubre] => 31000
        )
)
```

(en mis pruebas tan solo he creado un representante, pero ha de funcionar con varios sin problemas)

Para el caso de querer un objeto de vuelta, esto podria ser así:

```php
$meses = ['julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre'];

$array_objetos = [];
foreach ($ms as $objMS) {
    foreach ($cms as $objCMS) {
        if ($objMS->representante == $objCMS->representante) {
            $suma = new StdClass();
            $suma->representante = $objCMS->representante;
            foreach ($meses as $mes) {
                $suma->$mes = $objMS->$mes + $objCMS->$mes;
            }
            $array_objetos[] = $suma;
            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r((object)$array_objetos);
```

Lo cual nos devolveria algo así:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [representante] => Antonio
            [julio] => 6000
            [agosto] => 5000
            [septiembre] => 3000
            [octubre] => 31000
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [representante] => Pablo
            [julio] => 10200
            [agosto] => 2030
            [septiembre] => 131001
            [octubre] => 11
        )

)
```

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar, pruebo el código, y me lanza que estoy sumando string + string; creo que me esta tomando los meses del array meses como string y no para acceder al campo. te comento cualquier resultado que salga gracias :D

Comment: Que raro, yo lo he probado usando la clase para crear los arrays de objectos, pero no dispongo de los datos que sacas de tu base de datos... ¿Son números con decimales?  Y en caso afirmativo ¿que simbolo de decimal usan?

Comment: son campos int (enteros), estan asi en la base de datos, los sumo pero no ceo que en la suma se cambien de tipo;  voy a ver si accede al campo individualmente.

Comment: para depurar pon, debajo del `if` condicional, un print_r de los objetos, a ver que contienen:  `print_r($objMS);print_r($objCMS);die();`  y revisa lo que veas a ver si esta bien

Comment: ya funciono gracias, envio estos datos a la vista, retorne el array sum; accedoa a la vista pero no lee el atributo

Comment: mmm... ¿la vista que espera?  ¿un objeto? ¿o un array?  porque $suma es un array, no un objeto ni contiene objetos, sino otros arrays

Comment: La vista espera un objeto voy a convertir el array en objeto, y te cuento que tal me fue. pay o

Comment: Acabo de agregar a la respuesta lo mismo pero para objetos, lo que pasa es que no se como lo querias realmente pues no se como es la vista ni que estructura de objeto espera, pero espero que así ya te valga para terminarlo tu mismo de pulir.

Comment: Gracias, me has ayudado full. éxitos! :D